# Onworks default root password / how to define a root password

Tags: linux, sudo, password

I'm trying to use a linux server online on Onworks and tried some operations that needs sudo, and obviously I need the root password but don't know what's the default password for root.

So far, tried the blank input but failed. Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

The password for all the `onworks.net` servers is `123456`
[More Info](https://dev.to/17lwinn/onworks-how-to-run-ubuntu-online-cnm)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `sudo` then you don't need the root password, you need your own password -- assuming that that user has sudo access.

Answer (score 0):

AS Shadur said, the normal behaviour of sudo is to ask your own user password.
Of course, to modify the file /etc/sudoers you need root or sudo access.
"sudo visudo" or "visudo" from the root account, allows you to manipulate the /etc/sudoers file in a secured way (it checks syntax and manage multiple modifications).

Personnaly, I prefer giving access to a group instead of single users.

To give sudo acces to the wheel group without password :
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

For a single user :
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

"man sudoers" explains the file /etc/sudoers syntax on your OS.